# update number of new tweets every few seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like in Twitter, when there is new tweets it would automatically update the number of tweets I haven't checked. I am trying to write that sort of thing. below is what I got. I expect it to update the number every 5 secs on the element with numtweets class. It gives the max stack size error. How can I do this right?

```
    function updateNumber(item,className) {
    $('.'+className).text(item);
      setTimeout(updateNumber(steams.home.length, className), 5000);
    } 

    updateNumber(streams.home.length, 'numtweets');
```

Comment: You need to pass a function to `setTimeout`

Comment: modify it to this line:
      setTimeout(function () {updateNumber(steams.home.length, className)}, 5000);

Comment: great. it worked. thank you,all.